# These tables are not relating to each other nicely. How do I fix this?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, entity-relationship

I have following table with attributes:

**tblCourseInstructor**
    CourseId int NULL,
    InstructorId int NULL

[b]tblCourses[/b]
    CourseId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CourseName nvarchar(100) NULL,
    CourseDescription nvarchar(2000) NULL

**tblInstructors**
InstructorId int NULL,
    InstructorName nvarchar(50) NULL

**tblLocations**
    LocationId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Location nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Seating_Capacity int NULL,
    offers_inclass_training bit NULL,
    offers_online_training bit NULL,
    Available_Seating int NULL

**tblTrainingType**

TrainingTypeId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    TrainingType nvarchar(50) NOT NULL

**tblTrainingDates**

```
DateId] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
trainingDates datetime NOT NULL
```

History:

We are trying to create a training package at work where employees can take courses online.

That's why we came up with the tables above.

There is a main table where registered users and their course selection details will be stored.

The Challenges:

What we would like to do is present Course information screen.

This screen will ask employees to choose training location from the dropdown.

Once a training location is selected, details of the training for that location are displayed in a tabular format.

For instance, the name of course, the instructor, course description, and date and time of course.

If the employee is interested in this course, s/he will click a button to register to take this course.

Our big challenge is to tie the tables I listed above together so that when we query the tables, we are able to list the coursenames, instructors, locations, date and time, etc as described above.

Based on the tables I listed above, no key to tie all together.

In other words, they are not relating to each other in a way that allows for joins when we do the queries.

Can someone please help me with what I could possibly be missing?

Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said that the user will select location first ,then he will be shown the courses available for that location, So

**Step** 1: have  a key in the Course table that points to location. Note that in this case if you have the same course available in multiple locations then you will need to have that many records in this table for the same course.

```
tblCourses 
            CourseId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
            CourseName nvarchar(100) NULL, 
            CourseDescription nvarchar(2000) NULL
            LocationId int NOT NULL, (This is FK that connects to the location table)
```

**Step 2:** Connect the Table  tblCourseInstructor  using the CourseId to the tblCourses. Connect the tblCourseInstructor  to tblInstructors using InstructorId  These keys are already present in your tables.

**Step 3:** Add a TrainingTypeID in tblCourses to connect to tblTrainingType.

Final Structure of the tblCourses:

```
tblCourses 
                CourseId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
                CourseName nvarchar(100) NULL, 
                CourseDescription nvarchar(2000) NULL
                LocationId int NOT NULL, (This is FK that connects to the location table)
                TrainingTypeID  int NOT NULL  (This is FK that connects to the tblTrainingType table)
```

So based on the above relationships you can write the required queries and cascade each of the Dropdowns in the UI based on the selection(s) in the previous dropdown.

Comment: Thank you @SA for the prompt response. I mistakenly left out dates table. Please see above. 

Do I add dateId to tblCourses table?

Comment: Yes,can add the dateId to the Course table to get the course dates for a particular course.